Do any time series models actually assume strict stationarity?
I am taking a Time Series course, and we have covered the topic of Stationarity. The following definitions are given:

Strict Stationarity:
A stochastic process $\{X_t\}_{t \in T}$ is said to be strongly
stationary if for any finite set of time points $\{t_1, t_2, \ldots,
t_n\} \subset T$ and any time shift $h$, the joint distribution of
$(X_{t_1}, X_{t_2}, \ldots, X_{t_n})$ is identical to that of
$(X_{t_1+h}, X_{t_2+h}, \ldots, X_{t_n+h})$.
Weak Stationarity:
A stochastic process $\{X_t\}_{t \in T}$ is said to be weakly stationary (or wide-sense stationary) if:

The mean function $\mu(t) = E[X_t]$ is constant and does not depend on time $t$.

The autocovariance function $\gamma(t,t+h)$ only depends on $h$ but not on $t$.

The variance is finite.



It is then stated that many time series models (such as ARMA) assume Weak Stationarity. Furthermore, anytime "Stationary" is used, we should assume that the lecturer means "Weakly Stationary".
My question is: Do any Time Series models actually assume Strict Stationarity?

It seems unusual to introduce Strict Stationarity, and then
immediately disregard it in favour of Weak Stationarity.
Is Strict
Stationarity only taught as a pedagogical stepping stone to Weak
Stationarity, or is there an actual use case in real life?


When you calculate the ACF, you are assuming strict stationarity. So, it's kind of a thing underneath the hood that's always assumed. It's stronger than weak because it's saying that the whole joint distribution is time invariant rather than just the mean and the variance. Without that assumption, one couldn't calculate the acf of a time-series..

@mlofton Forgive my ignorance, but why can the ACF not be calculated for just a weakly stationary time series? Since the formula for ACF just involves fixed means/variances/covariances (for various t), and that is exactly what being weakly stationary offers?

Hi: No need for forgiveness. I experience it all the time.  Weak refers to the mean and variance being independent of time. But the covariance relation is implied by the joint distribution. So, when your calculating the acf which are the correlations or covariances, you need the strong stationarity because the summation term in the formula for the acf at any lag $\tau_{k}$, assumes that's true, namely $cov(x_{t},x_{t+k}) = cov(x_{(t-1)}, x_{(t+k-1)})$.

@mlofton, I believe this is still weak stationarity (WS). WS refers to not only means and variances but also covariances.

Hi Richard: There are so many definitions so I can't really say. I've seen weak refer to the mean and variance and strong refer to the joint distribution. The joint distribution implies the covariances. But I never saw weak refer to covariances ? If weak refers to covariances, then what does strong refer to ?

@mlofton, WS refers to first and second moments, and covariance happens to be a second moment (an element of the variance matrix of a joint distribution). I am pretty sure about that, and I do not share your impression about there being many definitions. Strong refers to the entire distribution.

I'll look up some definitions. Of course, whatever I find is not going to help much  because there are so many but I'll look anyway. As far as I know, covariance is not considered to be a second moment. But I'm not an expert on terminology. The distribution matters for calculating the acf because one needs $cov(y_t,y_{t+k})$ to be equal to $cov(y_{(t+1)}, y_{(t+k+1)})$ for any $k$.

Hi Richard: It's not so productive so I won't spend a lot of time on this but this one supports your statement. The covariance needs to be time-invariant for weak stationarity. http://www-stat.wharton.upenn.edu/~stine/stat910/lectures/02_stationarity.pdf

This one goes on and on and doesn't say what above says but I'm not sure what it's saying because it's says so much and becomes confusing. I would tend to go with Stine's handout rather than this.  https://www.timescale.com/learn/stationary-time-series-analysis

To the OP: Per Richard's comment,  if weak stationarity implies that covariance is time-invariant, then you don't need the strong stationarity to justify the calculation of the acf. To be honest, I'm not totally sure about the specifics of strong versus weak because I've seen too many different definitions.  I could probably spend more time and find five more links that will differ in some respect as to the definition. Thanks to Richard for pointing this out.

This one confirms Richard's statement also. So, I'm gonna go with Richard being correct.  https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/~bartlett/courses/153-fall2010/lectures/2.pdf If I get bored and look some more and find one that supports my original statement, I'll post it. It's somewhere !!!!! LOL.

Richard; I gave up looking. There's one out there somewhere that sides with me but, even then, I found soooo many that support the fact that cov being time invariant is a weak stationary criteria ). So, thanks for correction. I was wrong. To summarize,  one only needs strong stationarity if they have some candidate model that implies a density and they want to fit the density parameters. Other than that, weak seems like it covers most everything else.

@mlofton, thanks for all the work! Regarding your summary, I would have to think about it... I am afraid the statement is too simple to be "counterexampleproof" (as in waterproof)... Actually, I think this is a great question, and I would love to see one our expert users give it a full answer.

Hi Richard: yeah, no problem. I'd like to see an explanation also. Strong stationarity might be needed for ergodicity, a concept which I still haven't nailed down yet either. But, since ergodicity is not testable as far as I know, I don't worry about it. All the best.

In the communications and signal processing literature, the definition of wide-sense-stationary  (WSS) processes is that the mean is constant and the autocorrelation function $R(t,t+h)$ depends only on $h$, not on $t$. Processes for which the autocovariance  function $\gamma(t,t+h)$ depends only on $h$ are called covariance-stationary processes. Note the absence of any mention of the mean being constant in the latter definition. All WSS processes are covariance-stationary too but covariance-stationary processes need not be WSS. The prototypical example of a covariance-stationary ......

....  is a WSS process plus a deterministic signal.  See this answer of mine over on DSP.SE for a tutorial on random processes.

In general, weak stationarity is assumed to model the first and second order of a time series, because those are the most interesting for general use. ARMA, ARCH and GARCH models and variations all assume weak stationarity, however, there are cases where assuming a specific distribution for the series is important.
The simplest example is when normality is assumed, for the sake of creating prediction confidence bands, for instance. If you assume normality on top of weak stationarity, you are effectively assuming strong stationarity as well, because the first two moments define a Gaussian distribution completely.
Besides this, strict stationarity is not a very useful condition.
Alternatively, if you want to assume another non-Gaussian distribution for your series, there are specific models for that, like Generalized Autoregressive Score (GAS) models. In these cases, there can be a strict stationarity assumption, but it's not usually the focus of this types of models.

You mention GAS which is somewhat exotic (less well known), but what about ARMA with nonnormal errors or GARCH with nonnormal standardized innovations? At least the latter is fairly common.

if you mean non-normal in the sense that higher-order moments are not investigated, then that's just ordinary ARMA/ARCH/GARCH, and only weak stationarity is required. If you mean non-normal because a distribution different than Gaussian is assumed for the residuals, I'd say those are also quite exotic, but maybe that's just my impression

I mean Student-$t$ and other specific distributions. For ARMA they are exotic, I must admit, but for GARCH they are fairly common in my experience. My point was that you do not need a new model like GAS just to allow for a nonnormal distribution. (I have nothing against GAS per se, but that is besides the point.)

You are right. It didn't cross my mind before.
